# Bare-metal computer algebra system?

Tags: microcontroller, symbolic-math, algebra, bare-metal

I was looking for open source CAS online and realized there is no mention anywhere about an embedded CAS or bare-metal CAS in C (or some other language). Is it a waste of time and effort or is there any other reason for that? Maybe microcontrollers are not powerful yet but again there should be at least a mention of it.

Comment: The HP49G graphing calculator, which used the [Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Saturn) 4-bit microprocessor, had a CAS.  There is source code [here](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/english.html).  It's written in assembly and "medium-level" SysRPL.  This CAS grew out of earlier third-party software for the HP48G, which used the same CPU.  Does that meet your criteria?

Comment: But it is not bare-metal. Maybe it was in the beginning, but I dont see anything in its website. Closest I could find was [Mathomatic](http://mathomatic.orgserve.de/math/)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what the phrase "bare-metal" means to you.